# Spring CronExpression - Why remove support for year field?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-framework-beans

I have an application in spring boot, so naturally I used [CronExpression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html) which spring itself provides. But now I am starting to wonder - the old class [CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) was able to support cron expressions that has 7 fields(including year) and they depreciated it in favour of CronExpression.I understand they were moving away from an extra dependency on quartz. But why would they do it without supporting year too? I mean when compared to unix crons, they support and handle seconds field. The same way, couldn't they have supported year too?
Is there a reason why not having year field is better?

Comment: No it didn't. It always supported just 6 (as it also says in the documentation -> *The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday* from the documentation of `CronSequenceGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

The `CronSequenceGenerator` never supported 7 fields it has ever only supported 6 fields even since it inception in [Spring 3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

> The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

This comes from the documentation of the `CronSequenceGenerator` in Spring 3, and it remained the same more or less throughout the current version.

Another thing you misunderstood is that there is a dependency on Quartz, there isn't, the code parses it itself and doesn't use anything quartz related.